# How to fix [WinError 10061]?

Tags: python, mongodb, windows-10

I just started using mongoDB and I get the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I am using windows 10. Although not sure, I got from some possible answers that this is because the default location to search from a database is somewhere in C:/ and if you specify something else it crashes.

The errored line contains this: `my_client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")`

Any ideas on how to fix this? And if the error is indeed the location can I let my script now where to search for a database early in the script, so I can change that as well depending on the circumstances?

Thanks

Comment: Step 1: Throw the error at any search engine you like and read a few of the results. Step 2: If nothing helped, extract a [mcve] and post that along with your question.

Comment: Probably this is windows firewall blocking you.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The OP told us what the errored line is.